# Symfony add new data to retrieved object

Tags: php, symfony

I store my object data in a DB as ids. Say I have the following field stored in db as string:

```
2,3
```

and the following array stored some where in other place:

```
1 => low,
2 => medium,
3 => high
```

So when I retrieve this field in my twig template

```
{{ myobject.field }}
```

I get only 2,3, but I need something like

```
2 - medium, 3 - high
```

So I need to edit the data got in {{ myobject.field }} and add more info to it. What is the propoer way to do it with the help of Symfony? Is there something better than to manually reset object fields in foreach loop and overwrite the data stored there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to understand a little on how twig calls properties of objects.

```
{{ myobject.field }}
```

is essentially the same as:

```
$myObject->getField()
```

so, in the twig way of doing things, itll return whatever the `getter` returns.  So if you want a specific format of the data returned, either adjust the current `getField` method, or make a new one and call that instead.